# Update Target Android Version changes layout

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android, android-version

I need to update the target android version (I won't change the minimum android version) from 4.0.3 to 8.0.

When I change that and compile, all my activities loses the correct layout, all components stays bigger.

What can I do to change the target android and keep layout?

Comment: It's because of screen resolution on new version is higher . So you need to rewrite the layout .

Comment: Is there anyway to make it easier? My project has about 100 activities...

Comment: It is necessary if you want to your app deploy on so many device with different screen resolution  .